# How to write PHP Syntax in Smarty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, smarty

I want to know how to write php syntax in smarty template(.tpl).

For example I'm using below php syntax in Pure Codeigniter(No Smarty include) and it's working perfectly.

```
<?= isset($value) ? $value['phone'] : '' ?>
```

But in Smarty, It's not work. How should write this? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{if isset($value)}
    $value['phone']
{/if}
```

Comment: I think second method should be work. But i don't understand what is $title? Can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

years ago I used:

```
{php}
// php code
{/php}
```

Nowadays I don't know if it still works

Comment: Thanks alot bro. But In smarty 3 It's not working. I already tested it. Anyway thanks u for your answer. For now I can do it as #Arkadiusz G Said. 

{if isset($value)}
    $value['phone']
{/if}

This condition is working for me now.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30262065/454827 @KyawZinWai